# Can't fix carousel algorithm in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, carousel

I have a carousel of slides in my react.js project without using any libraries. When I use an odd amount of images everything works. But when I use even amount, although currentIndex is changing properly only odd images are displayed like 1,3,5 in this example with six images. Can anyone spot what is wrong with my code so it would work with ane amount of images not only with odd ones? Thanks very much

```
import React from 'react';
import Slide from './Slide';

import img1 from "../assets/img1.jpg";
import img2 from "../assets/img2.jpg";
import img3 from "../assets/img3.jpg";
import img4 from "../assets/img4.jpg";
import img5 from "../assets/img5.jpg";
import img6 from "../assets/img6.jpg";



class Test extends React.Component {
        state = {
        currentIndex: 0,
        images: [img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6]
        }

        prevSlide = () => {
        const lastIndex = this.state.images.length - 1;
        const resetIndex = this.state.currentIndex === 0;
        const index = resetIndex ? lastIndex : this.state.currentIndex - 1;
        this.setState({
          currentIndex: index
        });
      };

      nextSlide = () => {
        const lastIndex = this.state.images.length - 1;
        const resetIndex = this.state.currentIndex === lastIndex;
        const index = resetIndex ? 0 : this.state.currentIndex + 1;
        this.setState({
          currentIndex: index
        });
      };
    
      render() {
        const index = this.state.currentIndex;
        let newImagesArray = this.state.images.slice(index, index + 6);
        if (newImagesArray.length < 6) {
          newImagesArray = newImagesArray.concat(
            this.state.images.slice(0, 6 - newImagesArray.length)
          );
        }
        return (
          <div className="paint__container">
            {newImagesArray.map((image, i) =>
              this.state.currentIndex === i ? (
                <Slide key={i} url={image} alt="" />
              ) : null
            )}
                <div className="left__arrow" onClick={this.prevSlide}></div>
                <div className="right__arrow" onClick={this.nextSlide}></div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: So far I didn't spot any bug, but can you post the full code with how images are rendered, and if there is a place where the state could be changing from?

Comment: Maybe because of my English I am not sure what You need but here is a link to github and it is component Emotes.js in components folder: https://github.com/Pietrzi/strona-piotrb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, thank you for providing the full code, looking at the component on [github](https://github.com/Pietrzi/strona-piotrb/blob/master/src/components/Emotes.js)

we can find

- you have `nextSlide` defined twice, where the second I guess will overwrite the first declaration
- while you have the `currentIndex` in state why you are searching for the target slide in your render function? you don't have to do this my friend, while `currentIndex` correctly calculate the index then you just render the slide at that index, that's why we are using `react` after all

```js
render() {
    const index = this.state.currentIndex;
    const images = this.state.images;

    return (
        <div className="paint__container">
            <Slide url={images[index]} alt="" />
            <div className="left__arrow" onClick={this.prevSlide}></div>
            <div className="right__arrow" onClick={this.nextSlide}></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer, my mistake, `i` was the key passed to `Slide` component, but because we are not using `Slide` from an array anymore, we can remove it.